# How to make a 'Container' component in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to Vue and cannot find a way to implement a React-like 'Wrapper' component with Vue.js, for example, a reusable `datagrid` component using a 3rd-party `some-table` component and a `pagination` component. Intuitively, `datagrid` will provide the data/props/events that both components need and control the communication between them. In **React**, this could be done as simply as something like

```
// inside <Datagrid />
<Table {...someProps} />
<Pagination {...otherProps} />
```

With Vue, It seems like something like below can only pass `props` down to children components

```
// inside Datagrid.vue
<some-table v-bind="$props"></some-table>
```

I'm not sure if `slots` could be of help. This wrapper component that I've been struggling for takes all the `props/events/slots` its children need and pass them down to them so that I could utilize all the functionality that it's children(which probably some 3rd-party components) provide. Moreover, it may also take responsibility for something like data exchange between its children. While `datagrid` could be a slots wrapper, but what if both `table` and `pagination` require a same `data` prop which I think should reside in `datagrid`. How to pass this `data` down to the slots?

```
// Datagrid.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="table"></slot>
    <slot name="pagination"></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Datagrid',
  data() {
    return {
      data: 'How to share it with table and pagination',
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Some solutions that I could figure out:

1. [Render Functions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html), but I don't think that complicity is needed in this case
2. Instead of creating a 'Container' component, simply turn to [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html), but does this mean I have to input `<pagination :total="total" :other-props="are-same-for-all-datagrids"></pagination>` each time I want a datagrid?

Any examples dealing with such situations in Vue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Slots are exactly what you want.

Answer (score 10):

You want to use [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots):

```js
Vue.component('wrapper', { template: '#wrapper' })

new Vue({ el: '#app' })
```

```html
<!-- wrapper template -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper" style="background: beige; padding: 5px;">
    This is being wrapped: 
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</script>

<div id="app">
  <wrapper>
    <div style="background: aliceblue;">I'm being wrapped!</div>
  </wrapper>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What if I have two slots for example, and the children components that will be inserted require a same `tableData` prop. How to pass this `tableData` down to both slots so that when the parent updates, both children get informed?

Comment: Just pass the same variable as the `tableData` prop for both components.

Comment: I my case when creating named slots (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots#Named-Slots) I pass params to each of them: <slot name="header" v-bind:info="data">...</slot> (manual for scoped slots: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots#Scoped-Slots). Then you can access data using <template v-slot:header="info"><div>{{ info.<prop> }}</div></template>